# jquery if has been clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This I'm sure has a really easy answer:

I have a search form that when you focus on the form additional buttons pop under the form to allow you to filter choices, I'm trying to make it so on blur on the search form those options go away. Currently when you click on one of those options it closes the option menu, so I'm looking for a way to test if those options were clicked. Here is the code I've come up with so far:

```
    $("#search").blur(function(){
       $("#selector").click(function(){
           return false;
       });
       $("#selector").toggle();
    });
```

Also attempting to do something like the following yielded failing results:

```
    var is_clicked = true;
    $("#selector").click(function(){
        is_clicked = false;
    });
    console.log ( is_clicked ); // always returns true
```

Comment: change event to `mouseover` and `mouseout`

Comment: It's being done for mobile devices

Comment: not mentioned in OP. I have updated the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/gP8Jg/1/

```
 $("#search").blur(function(){
   $("#selector").mousedown(function(){
       return false;
   });
   $("#selector").toggle();
});
 $("#search").focus(function(){
   $("#selector").fadeIn();
});
```

Try to using `mousedown()` instead of `click()`

Comment: This works for the most part. If you click on search and then immediately click on #selector it still runs toggle the first time. After it has done that it works though. Any ideas why it's doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This always returns true because the console.log is executed synchronously:

```
var is_clicked = true;
$("#selector").click(function(){
    is_clicked = false;
    // console.log( is_clicked ); // will yeild false
});
console.log ( is_clicked ); // always returns true
```

I don't quite understand what you have done here:

```
$("#search").blur(function(){
   $("#selector").click(function(){
       return false; // Cancels the click
   });
   $("#selector").toggle(); // Slides vissible/hidden $('selector')
   // There is no code here that checks state of buttons or any other element
   // on the page.
});
```

Toggling an element upon click is done in it's own click handler:

```
$('#selector').click(function (event) {
    $('#selector').toggle();
});
```

Comment: ok so merging the two examples how do you go about only running `$("#selector").toggle()` when selector itself has not been clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to close the option menu after click on an option, toggle it with a delay, eg. use js `setTimeout()` and catch the click on the option element itself